# How to create multi version documentation site with Startlight and Astro?

Tags: astrojs, static-site-generation

I am trying to use Astro framework for the first time. I used the [Startlight](https://starlight.astro.build/) integration. But, how can I build a documentation site where each version may have an updated page.

For example, I have a `get-started.md` file that should be the same for version 1.0 and 2.0. But, the `how-to.md` file has different content for version 1.0 than version 2.0. So I need a way to create a site that supports multiple versions. Also, I would need to have a version selector that would default to `latest` when no version is selected.

I can't find a component that would allow me version my site as a typical documentation site would.

How can I use astro and starlight to create a multi-version documentation site?

Answer (score 0):

I'd just use something like the following folder structure in `src/content/`:

```
- docs/
  - get-started.md
  - 1.0/
    - how-to.md
  - 2.0/
    - how-to.md
```

For the selector, you can then just link to the correct pages.

Comment: thank you! But then how would I add a selector to the header where the user can switch between different versions?